# Ubuntu USB wont boot on Surface pro 3

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, microsoft-surface-pro

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the EFI partition of a USB drive with rEFInd as default bootloader. The OS runs without problems on my PC but wont boot on the Surface, instead it just "skips" it and boots to windows. I tried to start Ubuntu in the extended startoptions, by holding volume down when turning the device on, set the boot order to usb first, tried turning off secure boot, but nothing works